# Dispatched payload converted to [Object object]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to verify a JWT token each time the `created()` hook is called:

In my App.vue:

```
async created() {
if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token;
  console.log(token); //[CORRECT TOKEN STRING]
  await this.$store.dispatch("tryLogin", token);
}},
```

In my actions.js:

```
async tryLogin(context, payload) {
console.log(payload); //[CORRECT TOKEN STRING]
console.log(...payload); //(Spreding does not work)
return context.dispatch("verifyAuth", {
  payload,
});
},
```

Further down in my actions.js:

```
 async verifyAuth(context, payload) {
console.log(`inside VerifyAuth ${payload}`); //[Converted to: [object Object]]
// Above log Output: inside VerifyAuth [object Object]
let url = baseURL + "verify-token";
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("token", payload);

const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
  },
  body: formdata,
  redirect: "follow",
});

const responseData = await response.json();
}
```

For some reason once I do `return context.dispatch("verifyAuth", { payload, });` the payload changes from the actual stored string (token) to [object Object]

I tried spreading the payload which vields the same results.
I also tried `JSON.parse(console.log("inside VerifyAuth: " + payload));` with no luck
Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: No. I read though this post and I know that its a string representation of an Object, but what I don't understand is why it is not converted to string with the first `dispatch` and it is on the second

Comment: you know at `console.log(\`inside VerifyAuth ${payload}\`);` payload is an object - because you made it one, right? looks like `{payload: "the token string"}` ... so of course the console.log outputs what it does ... `({}).toString()` is always `[object Object]` ... what if you did `console.log(\`inside VerifyAuth ${payload.payload}\`);`

Comment: `console.log(\`inside VerifyAuth ${payload}\`);` will *turn your object to a string*. You should instead print the object itself to see it properly: `console.log(\`inside VerifyAuth\`, payload);`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. Both `console.log(`inside VerifyAuth ${payload}`);` and `console.log(`inside VerifyAuth`, payload);` vield the same result. The console log is there to simply see the output. Later in the code the `payload` is passed to the API call as a token. But something changed with it once it was `dispatched` because its no longer the token string

Comment: because you turned it into an object at `context.dispatch("verifyAuth", {payload,});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
context.dispatch("verifyAuth", {payload,});
```

dispatches an object, i.e. `{ payload: "the value of the variable payload" }`

so, either:

```
context.dispatch("verifyAuth", payload);
```

or

```
async verifyAuth(context, {payload}) {
```

or

```
formdata.append("token", payload.payload);
```

Comment: You my friend are a Wizzard! Thank you so much for your help!
edit: This solves the Issue. Again Thank you very much!

Comment: I was a bit worried when you said `console.log(\`inside VerifyAuth\`, payload);` still outputs `[object Object]` - because it shouldn't

Comment: Yes you are right, I missread your comment and wrote `console.log("inside VerifyAuth" + payload);` Note the `+` hence the same result.

Comment: wasn't my comment, but, yes, that would result in `.toString()` being called on the object too